# Test case for constructor as i have a filter logic

Tags: tdd, xunit, testcase

I have constructor where there is filter logic and wanna test it, though writing test case for constructor is not in practice i wanna have the code coverage , have tried many links but none are explaining about handling a constructor.

```
public Myclass {  
public Myclass(AnotherClass obj)    
{    
_key = obj.key;    
_ID = obj.ID;    
_CandidateMode = obj.CandidateMode;    
if(_CandidateMode == obj.CandidateMode.numeric     
{    
//Dosomething    
}    
else    
{    
//Do something with special character.    
}    
}    
}
```

Comment: If you test public methods of the class your constructor will be executed anyway, that mean constructor will be covered by tests.

Comment: I have public method tested there are some logic inside the constructor initialisation which I wanna test seperately !

Comment: Logic in the constructor should be tested through public methods or properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely placing logic inside a constructor is a thing to avoid. Good you know that :-) In this particular case maybe the `if` could go into each of the public methods of `MyClass`, or maybe you could use polymorphism (create `MyClass` or `MySpecialCharacterClass` base on the `AnotherClass` object)?

Anyway, to get to a straight answer: if you really must test constructor logic, do it like you would test any other method (in some languages it's just a static method called `new`, by the way).

```
[TestMethod]
public void is_constructed_with_numeric_candidate() {
  // Given
  AnotherClass obj = new AnotherClass { CandidateMode = CandidateMode.numeric };
  // When
  MyClass myClass = new MyClass(obj);
  // Then
  // assert myClass object state is correct for numeric candidate
  ...
}

[TestMethod]
public void is_constructed_with_special_candidate() {
  // Given
  AnotherClass obj = new AnotherClass { CandidateMode = CandidateMode.special };
  // When
  MyClass myClass = new MyClass(obj);
  // Then
  // assert myClass object state is correct for special candidate
  ...
}
```